# Is there any database, or reference, for retardation factors (Rf)?

Tags: chromatography

I'll like to compare the Rf of myrcene, obtained in Thin Layer Chromathography, for different species.  Toluene:Ethyl Acetate (97:3) would be fine, but is not a necessity.

Comment: There are just too many different solvents, and even more mixtures.

Comment: Is it not possible to create a database like this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No there is not database for retardation factors, because Rf values are useless outside your lab. It is not a fundamental property like melting point or boiling point. One batch of silica is slightly different from another. It also depends on exact solvent composition and history of the treatment of the stationary phase.

Comment: Even though the values will never match perfectly, I can't help but imagine there is some kind of information which could be extracted by performing a wide-ranging analysis on a large database, and even just having an approximate notion could be useful. I don't think this would ever get off the ground, though, people are already stingy about placing Rf information in suppinfo

Comment: @NicolauSakerNeto, There is a reason why there is no such database despite the fact that chromatography is a century old technique. Silica and alumina behavior is heavily dependent on their history of manufacture and moisture content. It is useful to state the typical mobile phase and stationary phase on TLC. There are thick books on TLC theory and practice.